# Why do the odd moments of the interaction Hamiltonian vanish w.r.t. a reference state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

When deriving the Nakajima-Zwanzig equation in *The Theory of Open Quantum Systems* by Breuer and Pettrucione, in Eq. 9.10, they state that

> In many cases it may also be assumed that the odd moments of the interaction Hamiltonian with respect to the reference state vanish, $\mathrm{Tr}_B[H_I(t_1)H_I(t_2)\dots H_I(t_{2n+1})\rho_B]=0$,

where $\mathrm{Tr}_B$ is the trace with respect to the bath, $H_I$ is the interaction Hamiltonian, $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $\rho_B$ is the state of the environment, often taken to be a Gibbs state. This results in the following relation: $$\mathcal{P}\mathcal{L}(t_1)\mathcal{L}(t_2)\dots\mathcal{L}(t_{2n+1})\mathcal{P}=0,$$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is the projection super-operator to the relevant part of the system and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Liouvillian, which is used later to simplify the resulting Nakajima-Zwanzig equations of motion.

My question is in what specific cases can this be assumed and how is it justified?

Answer (score 1):

In practice, it is because usually the (microscopic) interaction Hamiltonian is usually linear in a bath/environment field, *aka*
$$
H_{I}(t) = O_{\mathrm{system}}(t) \otimes \phi_{B}(t) \ ,
$$
(where $O_{\mathrm{system}}$ is some operator on the system) and odd numbers of $H_{I}$ operators in a trace end up depending on odd-numbered expectation values of fields
$$
\mathrm{Tr}_{B}[H_{I}(t_1) \cdots H_{I}(t_{2n+1})\rho_{B}] \propto O'_{\mathrm{system}}(t_1,\ldots ,t_{2n+1}) \times \mathrm{Tr}_{B}[\phi_{B}(t_1) \cdots\phi_{B}(t_{2n+1})\rho_{B}] \ ,
$$
(for some other operator $O'_{\mathrm{system}}$). It is a general result that usually odd-numbers of fields in an expectation value vanish (for example $\langle 0|\phi(t)|0\rangle = 0$ in a vacuum state).

Note this doesn't necessarily have to be true in general, but a huge amount of the examples studied in the literature have interactions of this form (and for sure in Breuer's book).

Comment: Is this for interactions where $O_\text{system}(t)$ is some raising/lowering operator on the system and $\phi_B(t)$ is a lowering/raising operator on the bath?